# JAVA JAI: between Jai Jars and Jai Setups, what should i use to get faster and more efficient result?

Tags: java, jar, installation, jai

I have jai (Java Advance Imaging ) which i am using in my application.

When i am using jai setups  i feel my image-processing is faster but it requires these setups to be installed in users computer.

And When i Use Jars of jai it does not require any installation but image-processing is bit slow.

So What approach should i use to get faster and more efficient result?

Is there any way i can install jai setups silently which does not require any user interaction at a time of instillation?

Comment: Very good question... +1... I wanted to know the same...

Answer (score 2):

I think that performance difference you see is caused by JAI running with or without hardware acceleration. To get hardware acceleration, you have to:

- or install JAI in to JRE (then proper JARs/DLLs/SO files are copied to JRE and are available then to any Java application)
- or provide JAR/DLL/SO files with your java application. In this case **no installation is required!**

To implement the second option you have to:

- include 
  `jai_codec-1.1.3.jar 
  jai_core-1.1.3.jar 
  mlibwrapper_jai.jar` 
  to your application and add them to the classpath
- put
  `libmlib_jai.so 
  mlib_jai.dll 
  mlib_jai_mmx.dll 
  mlib_jai_util.dll` 
  to working folder of your application

If you run on Lynux, you'll probably need to extend `LD_LIBRARY_PATH` with the working dir,  to tell java where to find SO file:

```
#!/bin/bash

ROOT=`dirname $0`
cd $ROOT

# allow JINI to load libraries from working directory 
# (e.g. libmlib_jai.so - JAI hardware acceleration library) 
export LD_LIBRARY_PATH=$ROOT:$LD_LIBRARY_PATH
```

**Example:**

Your application structure may be:

```
YourApplication
    lib
        jai_codec-1.1.3.jar 
        jai_core-1.1.3.jar 
        mlibwrapper_jai.jar        
        ...
    libmlib_jai.so 
    mlib_jai.dll 
    mlib_jai_mmx.dll 
    mlib_jai_util.dll
    ...
    run.cmd
    run.sh
    ...
```

So, the JARs are included to the CLASSPATH, and the SO/DLLs are in the working folder (where `run.cmd/.sh` are executed).